How to use the tedious definitional results to make a next definition for FindRoot?
I am trying to use a designed function to find the quasi-normal modes.
LEAVER[\[Omega]_, s_, l_, 
  NITMAX_] := (\[Alpha][i_, j_] = Function[j, xs[i]];
  Do[\[Alpha][i, j] = 0, {i, 4, 22}, {j, 0, i - 4}];
  fs = Table[\[Alpha][i, j], {i, 1, 22}, {j, 0, NITMAX}];
  Do[fs = 
    FoldList[
     If[PossibleZeroQ[#2 // Last], #2 // 
        Most, (Most[#2] - (#2 // Last)/(#1 // Last)*
           Prepend[#1 // Most, 0]) // Together] &, 
     fs // First // Most, fs // Rest], {19}];
  (*Gauss elimination*)
  rl = fs;
  Leaver31 = Module[{Rn = -1.0},
    
    Do[Rn = rl[[n, 3]]/(rl[[n, 2]] - rl[[n, 1]]*Rn), {n, NITMAX, 
      2, -1}];
    
    Rn];
    Leaver33 = rl[[1, 2]]/rl[[1, 1]] - Leaver31)

fun[x_?NumberQ] := LEAVER[x, 0, 1, 100]
winit = 0.5 + 0.2 I;

Then the FindRoot command doesn't run as I anticipated.
In[37]:= FindRoot[fun[x] == 0, {x, winit}]

During evaluation of In[37]:= Function::flpar: Parameter specification 0 in Function[0,xs[1]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

During evaluation of In[37]:= Function::flpar: Parameter specification 1 in Function[1,xs[1]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

During evaluation of In[37]:= Function::flpar: Parameter specification 2 in Function[2,xs[1]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

During evaluation of In[37]:= General::stop: Further output of Function::flpar will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[37]= $Aborted

I don't know how to define the function Leaver[\[Omega]_,s_,l_,NITMAX] properly，because the values xs[i] appeared elsewhere tediously, which look like
(*From the Frobenius series obtaining the recurrence relation, in which xs[i] are coefficeints*)

Do[xs[n_] := (n + 3 - i) (n + 2 - i) CoefficientListMatrix[[1, 
     i]] + (n + 3 - i) CoefficientListMatrix[[2, i]] + 
   CoefficientListMatrix[[3, i]]; xs[i] = xs[n]; Print[xs[i]], {i, 22}]

-3.55271*10^-15 (1+n) (2+n)(*xs[1]*)

3.55271*10^-15 n (1+n)+(1+n) (5.32907*10^-15-(0. +3.55271*10^-15 I) \[Omega])(*xs[2]*)

1.11022*10^-15+2.25*10^-6 (-1+n) n-1.11022*10^-15 s+n (2.25*10^-6-(0. +3.*10^-6 I) \[Omega])-2.22045*10^-15 \[Omega]^2(*xs[3]*)

...

(*Output 22 coefficients*)

My question is that how to use the above result of xs[i] to set the values of \[Alpha][i_, j_] = xs[i][j] in the definition of LEAVER[\[Omega], s, l, NITMAX] concisely.

Function[j, xs[i]] where j is numeric, is a syntax error. j needs to be  a formal parameter used in the function definition.

@ Daniel Huber Thank you for your comments. Could you give me more specific suggestions to revisit this problem and define a good function Leaver?

The code is a bit confusing to me. Why did you aside against using \[Alpha][i_, j_] = xs[i][j]? Or simply xs[i][j]? I don't think Function does what you think it does. Later, xs[n_] is defined in such a way that xs[i][j] doesn't make sense: Are you confusing single backets [] with double brackets [[]]? If you are trying to construct a sequence of assignments, it might be easier to create a list of the values and then assign them. More specific suggestions are not really possible (at least from me, sorry).

@Michael E2 Thank you for your useful comments. I am trying to understand the brackets.

E.g. to define a function that calculates the square of its argument you would write Function[x, x^2] where x must be s symbol without any value assigned.

@Daniel Huber Thanks for your clarification.

If it helps: The double brackets list[[j]] are used to extract the j-th element (or Part) of the list. Some programming languages use single brackets for this. In Mathematica, single brackets are used for functions; for instance, $\sin(x)$ would be Sin[x]. Function does seem on the surface does not appear to be needed for your code, but since I don't understand completely, I could be wrong.

@Michael E2 I have used the following command xs = Function[{i, n}, (n + 3 - i) (n + 2 - i) CoefficientListMatrix[[1, i]] + (n + 3 - i) CoefficientListMatrix[[2, i]] +CoefficientListMatrix[[3, i]]] resolving the definition.
